# Como mudar projeto padrão no FIrebase via terminal?

Tags: html, css, firebase, google

estou tentando hospedar um website no firebase, segui corretamente os passos que me foram orientados pela plataforma.
Eu defini um projeto padrão na etapa do "firebase init" e agora quero definir outro, mas não faço ideia de como fazer.
Nem a documentação, nem o "firebase deploy help" informam isso claramente, e estou começando a perder as esperanças. help!!

Comment: Você quer iniciar outro projeto do firebase?

Comment: Você definiu o projeto padrão em um diretório. Se você quiser criar outro projeto, abra um outro diretório e faça o `firebase init`

Answer (score 1):

poderá usar o comando do Firebase seguinte: Firebase use < alias >

Onde está alias, será o nome do projeto que você criou.